# Use truth tables to show logical equivilance

Tags: logic

Q: Show using truth tables that $\lnot(p \to q)$ and $(p \land q)$ are logically equivalent.

So I thought that the negation of $(p \to q)$ was $(p \land \lnot q)$ so not sure if "logically equivalent" means their truths tables have to be identical or if they only need to have the same number of True and same number of false?

Comment: You're right, "equivalent" means that the truth tables must be identical in every row. Is it possible that you misread the question?

Comment: They aren't equivalent. You're right that $\neg (p\to q) \equiv (p\land \neg q)$.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{matrix}
   P & Q & \sim Q & P\to Q & \sim (P\to Q) & P\wedge \sim Q & P\wedge Q  \\
   T & T & F & T & F & F & T  \\
   T & F & T & F & T & T & F  \\
   F & T & F & T & F & F & F  \\
   F & F & T & T & F & F & F  \\
\end{matrix}